# How to put column name in ALV Display

Tags: abap

I have a definition like this:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_workarea,
          data1 TYPE string,
          data2 TYPE string,
          data3 TYPE string,
       END OF ty_workarea.

DATA gt_data  TYPE TABLE OF ty_workarea.
```

Fields (data1, data2, data3) don't have any column name when I output it (gt_data) in ALV (cl_salv_table). How can I put name for them?

And since they have empty column names, I'm unable to do this trick:

```
  lo_columns = go_alv->get_columns( ).

  lo_column = lo_columns->get_column( 'CURRENT_NAME' ).

  lo_column->set_long_text( 'NEW_NAME' ).
```

Comment: The column names are `HEADER1`, etc. Naming a column "header" is weird. The header texts are set by SET_LONG_TEXT for instance, they are not contained in `GT_DATA`.

Comment: @SandraRossi Yes you are right, I changed them to "column1" etc. So there is no way to put a name for them in ALV?

Comment: What I first said is still valid, even after fixing the names. Now, the column names are `COLUMN1`, etc. When you say "column name", I guess you mean the column header text. When I say "column name", I mean the technical name used by CL_SALV_TABLE.

Comment: @SandraRossi Pardon me. Fixed again.

Comment: In fact, I have answered your question since my first comment I think. It's just that you don't understand that when I tell you to use the column name `DATA1`, I mean you must use `lo_column = lo_columns->get_column( 'DATA1' ).` (moreover, the `get_column` parameter is named `columnname`, so understand that it means "get the column named `DATA1`")

Comment: @SandraRossi Thank you so so much. I don't know what this community do without you around here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_column` method expects the name of the field it represents, not the current heading text. So

```
lo_column = lo_columns->get_column( 'DATA1' ).
```

should get you the column you want.

Alternatively, the class `CL_SALV_COLUMNS_TABLE` (the one behind the `lo_columns` object) also has a method `get` which returns an internal table with the names and corresponding `CL_SALV_COLUMN` objects of all the  columns. This can be useful in a context where you don't know the names of the columns you want to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Columns names are taken by default from dict. You can try to use Sap elements or if you want to have custom title , you may define your own data element.

e.g use type MATNR instead of STRING for DataX and the title will be displayed for that column.